# df.replace call does not make changes to the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

With `pd.DataFrame.replace`, I have been trying to figure out why the values that I replaced revert back to their original values when I replace another set in another column. How can you make the replacements permanent, below?

```
titanic.replace({'Pclass' : 
                {3 : 'Lower Class', 
                 2 : 'Middle Class', 
                 1: 'Upper Class'}})
```

Comment: You have to assign the result using titanic = titanic.replace(.... or use parameter inplace = True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code `titanic.replace(...)` creates a *new* `DataFrame`, and returns that. In order to have Python remember this `DataFrame` later instead of just getting rid of it, you need to assign it to something, with `df = titatic.replace(...)`. Here `df` can be any name, *including* `titanic`; if you use the same name, it will get rid of the *old* `DataFrame` and use the new one from then on.

Answer (score 3):

Read the [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas-dataframe-replace) documentation:

> ```
> DataFrame.replace(to_replace=None, value=None, inplace=False, 
>                        limit=None, regex=False, method='pad', axis=None)
> ```
>
> Replace values given in `to_replace` with `value`.

---

> Returns:   `filled` : `NDFrame`

This isn't an in-place operation unless you specify it to be so.

```
titanic.replace({'Survived':(0:'False',1:'True')}, inplace=True)
```

or, assign the return value back.

```
titanic = titanic.replace({'Survived':(0:'False',1:'True')})
```

Don't try assigning when `inplace=True` because then, `df.replace` returns `None`.

Comment: thanks. i am very new to programming and it's hard for me to understand the documentation. your answer here helped a lot though.

Comment: @techscolasticus If my answer helped, you can mark it accepted. Thank you.

Comment: @coldspeed. I tried marking it as accepted but then it removes the mark from Daniel H's answer which was a bit easier for me to understand why my original method didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

add inplace =True

```
titanic.replace({'Survived':(0:'False',1:'True')},inplace =True)
```

Also for kaggle titanic data, recommend `map`

```
d={0:'False',1:'True'}

titanic.Survived=titanic.Survived.map(d)
```

Comment: what does map do? sorry, i'm very new to programming in general and have trouble understanding pandas documentation.

Comment: @techscolasticus think about 'map' is 'merge', In your example , If value =0 after map it will return `False`, just like a dictionary , 0-->False